# Basic logic: modus ponens and left-nested conditionals

Tags: logic

Consider (1) and (2):

(1) *(a ⊃ b) ⊃ a*

(2) *a*

do (1) and (2) together with modus ponens entail (3) *b*? My guess is no, but am I right? Could someone explain why?

Comment: Correct. To prove it, use truth table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. To appply modus ponens with $a$ as one of the premises to conclude $b$, you would need as a second premise an implication of the form $(a ⊃ b)$. But there is no such premise among the formulas you gave, so modus ponens is not applicable.

The inference is invalid because with $a \mapsto True, b \mapsto False$ there exists a counter model which makes both premises true but the conclusion false.